# How to add more nodes to nodes on a NSOutlineView like a directory tree?

Tags: swift, macos, nsoutlineview

I would like to get and show the user home directory on a NSOutlineView going deep every time the node is expandable.

So far I can get only the first level and expand it to a second level.

I imagine that it has to be appended to an index or something like that.

I can get level 1 and 2. When i click on the level 2, for example Documents, there is a directory, yourDirectoryName, that has more directories in it. I would like to show the arrow and be able to keep going further on the tree

First pic is my app. Second pic is an example from filezilla

[image: My app currently shows it]

[image: An example of would it has to be]

```
import Cocoa
class Directories {
var name: String
var subDirectories: [String]

init(name: String, subDirectories: [String]) {
    self.name = name
    self.subDirectories = subDirectories
}
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {
var directories = [Directories]()
@IBOutlet weak var outlineView: NSOutlineView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getDir(path: "")
    outlineView.dataSource = self
    outlineView.delegate = self
}



func getDir(path: String) {
     let fm = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser

    do {
        let items = contentsOf(folder: fm)
        for item in items {
            let sub = getSubDir(path: item.lastPathComponent)
            let re = Directories(name: item.lastPathComponent, subDirectories: sub)
            directories.append(re)
        }
    }
}

func contentsOf(folder: URL) -> [URL] {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do {
        let contents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: folder.path)

        let urls = contents.map { return folder.appendingPathComponent($0) }
        return urls
    } catch {
        return []
    }
}

func getSubDir(path: String) -> [String]{
    var sub = [String]()
    let fm = FileManager.default
    let filePath = NSString(string: path).expandingTildeInPath
    do {
        let items = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: filePath)
        for item in items {
            sub.append(item)
        }
    } catch {
        // failed to read directory
    }
    return sub
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
}



extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDataSource {
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any {
    if let directories = item as? Directories {
        return directories.subDirectories[index]
    }
    return directories[index]
}

func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
    if let directories = item as? Directories {
        return directories.subDirectories.count > 0
    }
    return false
}

func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
    if let directories = item as? Directories {
        return directories.subDirectories.count
    }
    return directories.count
}
}

extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDelegate {
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
    var text = ""
    if let directories = item as? Directories {
        text = directories.name
    }
    else {
        text = item as! String
    }

    let tableCell = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "cell"), owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
    tableCell.textField!.stringValue = text
    return tableCell
}
}
```

Comment: Is the question how to make the data a tree or is the question how to load a subdirectory when a node is expanded?

Comment: I can get level 1 and 2. When i click on the level 2, for example Documents, there is a directory, yourDirectoryName, that has more directories in it. I would like to show the arrow and be able to keep going further on the tree.

Comment: Do you want to load a tree of all subdirectories into `directories` or do you want to load the subdirectory when a node is expanded?

Comment: When it is expanded. For example, if I access an external drive with too many subdirs, it would take a while to read and store all the names... So, i think when clicking on it would be a better aproach

Comment: An item is expandable if it's a directory. Load the subdirectory when the item is expanded.

Comment: I can get the first level and second level. How do I append more levels when i click on the second level?

Comment: Call `getSubDir`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192732/discussion-between-renan-aguiar-and-willeke).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding level 2 to 3 is the same as expanding level 1 to 2. A subdirectory is a directory and has its own subdirectories. The `subDirectories` property of `Directories` should be an array of `Directories`. The `directories` property of `ViewController` points to a tree of directories and can be a `Directories`.

Example:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    // the rootItem is invisible
    var rootItem = DirectoryItem(url: FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser)

}


extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDataSource {

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
        let directoryItem = item as? DirectoryItem ?? rootItem
        return directoryItem.childItems.count
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any {
        let directoryItem = item as? DirectoryItem ?? rootItem
        return directoryItem.childItems[index]
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
        let directoryItem = item as? DirectoryItem ?? rootItem
        return directoryItem.isExpandable
    }

}


extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDelegate {

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
        let directoryItem = item as? DirectoryItem ?? rootItem
        let tableCell = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: (tableColumn?.identifier)!, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        tableCell.textField!.stringValue = directoryItem.name
        return tableCell
    }

}


class DirectoryItem {

    var name: String
    var url: URL

    lazy var isExpandable: Bool = {
        do {
            return try url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey]).isDirectory ?? false
        } catch let error as NSError {
            return false
        }
    }()

    lazy var childItems: [DirectoryItem] = {
        do {
            let urls = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url,
                    includingPropertiesForKeys: [.isDirectoryKey],
                    options: [.skipsHiddenFiles])
            return urls.map { DirectoryItem(url: $0) }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            return []
        }
    }()

    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
        self.name = url.lastPathComponent
    }

}
```

Disclaimer: I'm used to Objective-C and I'm struggling with Swift.

Comment: i got: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: i couldnt trace it... but it happens when i run it

Comment: Maybe this helps: [What does “fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: Works: extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDelegate {
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
        var text = ""
        if let directories = item as? DirectoryItem {
            text = directories.name
        }
        else {
            text = item as! String        }        
        let tableCell = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "cell"), owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        tableCell.textField!.stringValue = text
        return tableCell
    }
}